# Calculate the decision boundary for Quadratic Discriminant Analysis (QDA)

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics, machine-learning

I am trying to find a solution to the decision boundary in QDA. The question was already [asked and answered for linear discriminant analysis (LDA)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92157/compute-and-graph-the-lda-decision-boundary), and the solution provided by amoeba to compute this using the "standard Gaussian way" worked well. However, I am applying the same technique for a 2 class, 2 feature QDA and am having trouble. Would someone be able to check my work and let me know if this approach is correct?

I start-off with the discriminant equation,
$\delta_c = -\frac{1}{2}\log{|\mathbf{\Sigma_c}|}-\frac{1}{2}{\mathbf{(x-\mu_c)'\Sigma^{-1}_l(x - \mu_c)}}+\log{p_c}$

Where $\delta_c$ is the discriminant score for some observation $[x,y]$ belonging to class $c$ which could be 0 or 1 in this problem.

The decision boundary between $c=0$ and $c=1$ is the set of poins $\{\boldsymbol{\vec{x}}, \boldsymbol{\vec{y}}\}$ that satisfy the criteria $\delta_0$ equal to $\delta_1$. To find this set of points, I start with:

$$\delta_0=\delta_1$$

Substitute the discriminant equation for both $\delta_0$ and $\delta_1$

$$-\frac{1}{2}\log{|\mathbf{\Sigma_0}|}-\frac{1}{2}{\mathbf{(x-\mu_0)'\Sigma^{-1}_0(x - \mu_0)}}+\log{p_0} = -\frac{1}{2}\log{|\mathbf{\Sigma_1}|}-\frac{1}{2}{\mathbf{(x-\mu_1)'\Sigma^{-1}_1(x - \mu_1)}}+\log{p_1}$$

After some algebra obtain:
$${\mathbf{(x-\mu_1)'\Sigma^{-1}_1(x - \mu_1)}}-{\mathbf{(x-\mu_0)'\Sigma^{-1}_0(x - \mu_0)}}=C$$
Where $C = \log{|\mathbf{\Sigma_0}|}-\log{|\mathbf{\Sigma_1}|}+2\log{p_1}-2\log{p_0}$

In the next part I am attempting to solve for $\boldsymbol{\vec{y}}$ given some input $\boldsymbol{\vec{x}}$.
to find $\boldsymbol{\vec{y}}$ I re-wrote the previous equation as the following:

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & y_1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ \end{bmatrix} -  \begin{bmatrix} x_0 & y_0 \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} p & q \\ r & s \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \\ \end{bmatrix} = C$$

Where (for now): 
$$x_0 = x-\mu_{00}$$
$$y_0 = y-\mu_{01}$$
$$x_1 = x-\mu_{10}$$
$$y_1 = y-\mu_{11}$$

After a lot of algebra I eventually found the solution to be:

$$(d-s)y^2+(-2d\mu_{11}+2s\mu_{01}+bx-b\mu_{10}+cx-c\mu_{10}-qx+q\mu_{00}-rx+r\mu_{00})y = C-a(x-\mu_{10})^2+p(x-\mu_{00})^2+b\mu_{11}x+c\mu_{11}x-q\mu_{01}x-r\mu_{01}x+d\mu_{11}^2-s\mu_{01}^2-b\mu_{10}\mu_{11}-c\mu_{10}\mu_{11}+q\mu_{01}\mu_{00}+r\mu_{01}\mu_{00}$$

Apply the quadratic formula to solve for $y$:
$u = d-s$
$v = -2d\mu_{11}+2s\mu_{01}+bx-b\mu_{10}+cx-c\mu_{10}-qx+q\mu_{00}-rx+r\mu_{00}$
$w = C-a(x-\mu_{10})^2+p(x-\mu_{00})^2+b\mu_{11}x+c\mu_{11}x-q\mu_{01}x-r\mu_{01}x+d\mu_{11}^2-s\mu_{01}^2-b\mu_{10}\mu_{11}-c\mu_{10}\mu_{11}+q\mu_{01}\mu_{00}+r\mu_{01}\mu_{00}$
$$y = \frac{-v\pm\sqrt{v^2-4uw}}{2u}$$

When I solve for $\boldsymbol{\vec{y}}$ I obtain this decision boundary:

[image: Incorrect Decision Boundary]

To check my work I calculated the difference of two bi-variate Gaussians, based on the same data, across the entire plot area to obtain:

[image: QDA Decision Boundary as Difference of Bi-variate Gaussians]

There are errors in my work, and I was wondering is the group would be kind enough to review this question and provide some input on what went wrong?

Pardon my notation, I am relatively new to this math.

(Note: I previously posted [this question](http://Calculate%20the%20decision%20boundary%20for%20Quadratic%20Discriminant%20Analysis%20(QDA)) on the Cross-Validated subgroup, but have not received any responses.)

Answer (score 3):

The discriminant equation:
$$
(x-\mu_1)'\Sigma^{-1}_1(x-\mu_1) - (x-\mu_2)'\Sigma^{-1}_2(x-\mu_2) = C
$$
should be reduced to an equation of conic section, i.e., in the form of:
$$
Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2=D
$$
instead of using uni-variate quadratic formula:
$$
x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
$$
which will give incorrectly the two curve lines (green and blue lines).

Green line:
$$
x=\frac{-b+ \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
$$
Blue line:
$$
x=\frac{-b- \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
$$